# iOS: ImageMagick compiler warnings in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, imagemagick, cocoapods

I am using ImageMagick in an iOS project, however the library is outdated because the previous developer used the source code for this. I am using Xcode 6.3.2 and I want to use Cocoapods to integrate ImageMagick in the project instead of copying the source files. However when I integrate ImageMagick with Cocoapods I get four compiler warnings.

This is the content of my pods file:

```
target 'MyProject' do
    pod 'ImageMagick', '6.8.8-9'
end
```

These are the 4 warnings:

[image]

If I try to change the file I get this warning popup

[image]

And I can't unlock the file, I get this other error

[image]

I am not that familiar with ImageMagick.

Are these warnings important? 
Should I change the .h file and configure it properly?
How can I unlock this file?
Any ideas on what I should configure to eliminate these warnings?

Is this the way to go? It doesn't feel right to modify a file inside a Cocoapod.

Answer (score 1):

In CocoaPods there is already compiled version of ImageMagick. So you need to define these macros only for your target to hide the warnings. As I understood, they won't change anything in ImageMagick, because it was already compiled.

So, open `Preprocessor Macros` settings for your target or if you have several targets, for your whole project:

[image: settings]

And add 2 variables for both "Debug" and "Release":

`MAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0
MAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16`

[image: variables]

Answer (score 0):

You should set `MAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH` to 0, 16, 32, or 64 in a preprocessor macro.

You should also set `MAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE` to `YES` or `NO`

To do that, you can either change your preprocessor macros to have those values, or you can use a [post-install hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046282/debug-preprocessor-macro-not-defined-for-cocoapods-targets) from [CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html) to set those for you every time you run `pod install`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't see how a post-install hook could help me here. I've tried your suggestions but I still see the 4 warnings.

Comment: The post install hooks are to automate adding preprocessor macros. If you have configured the post install hooks correctly, run `pod install` and the preprocessor macros should be added. Then build and run. The error is there because some macros aren't defined.

Comment: Post install could be great but this is a second step for me. I have modified added the preprocessor macros you wrote but I still get 4 warnings. Until I do not solve this manually I cant think of automation. First, solve it manually, this is my problem. It will help me a lot if you post some code.

Comment: I can't post any code, its a preprocessor thing :p. Remember to click the pods project and select the appropriate target that refers to ImageMagick and the target in the main project (something like Target-ImageMagick). Then configure the preprocessor macros there. Finally clean and build :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I ended up copying the source files inside my project. I can't waist my time anymore to get this working.