# How to add swift compiler custom flag through XCode templates

Tags: ios, xcode, templates

I've try to add swift compiler custom flag in target through XCode Templates

**Default**

[image: swift compiler custom flag in target]

---

```
<key>Targets</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Configurations</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Debug</key>
                <dict/>
                <key>Release</key>
                <dict/>
            </dict>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>___PACKAGENAME___</string>
            <key>SharedSettings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS</key>
                <array>
                    <key>Debug</key>
                    <string>-DDEBUG</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

---

**Template**

[image: Xcode Templates]

I want to access only debug key. Is it possible?

Comment: Please see maybe answer here is helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046282/debug-preprocessor-macro-not-defined-for-cocoapods-targets

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there!

This is how the `TemplateInfo.plist` should look like

```
<key>Targets</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Configurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Debug</key>
            <dict>
                <key>OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS</key>
                <array>
                    <string>-DDEBUG</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

[image: TemplateInfo.plist]

And here is the result

[image: Build Settings]